# How to check DFSR or FRS for Sysvol Replication with Powershell?

Tags: active-directory, replication, sysvol

I've been investigating how to check whether DFSR or FRS for Sysvol Replication is used with powershell. Here is my naive methods, I have tried to implement.

1. Check if the DFS replication is installed

PS C:> Get-WindowsFeature|where Displayname -Match "Replication"

```
Display Name                                            Name                       Install State
------------                                            ----                       -------------
        [ ] DFS Replication                             FS-DFS-Replication             Available
```

So, this proves that it's using FRS over DFSR??

2. Check DN

   ```
   $FRSsysvol = "CN=Domain System Volume (SYSVOL share),CN=File Replication Service,CN=System,"+(Get-ADDomain $domain).DistinguishedName
   $DFSRsysvol = "CN=Domain System Volume,CN=DFSR-GlobalSettings,CN=System,"+(Get-ADDomain $domain).DistinguishedName

   $frs = Get-ADObject -Filter { distinguishedName -eq $FRSsysvol }
   $dfsr = Get-ADObject -Filter { distinguishedName -eq $DFSRsysvol } 


   if ( $frs -ne $null ) { Write-Host -ForegroundColor red "FRS" }

   elseif ( $dfsr -ne $null ) { Write-Host -ForegroundColor green "DFS-R" }

   else { Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "unknown" }
   ```

This returns "FRS". But when I double check `$frs` and `$dfsr` output. Both are not `$null`. Both return DN, Name, ObjectClass and ObjectGUID as well. So, What's problem here?

Comment: The `Get-WindowsFeature` just shows all available Windows features. In your example the `[ ]`, and `Install State 'Available'`, indicates the feature is available but not installed. An installed feature will have will appear as `[X]` with `Install State 'Installe'`. Try `Get-WindowsFeature | ? { $_.'InstallState' -eq 'Installed' }`. Moreoever, the general utility for querying FRS migration is `Dfsrmig /getmigrationstate`.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: @Sorcha tks for the answer. I knew the `Get-WindowsFeature` properties and so on. I have tried to run the `Dfsrmig /getmigrationstate`. It returns nothing. @jscott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the way how to implement this, hope this help!

```
        $currentDomain =(Get-ADDomainController).hostname

        $defaultNamingContext = (([ADSI]"LDAP://$currentDomain/rootDSE").defaultNamingContext)
        $searcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
        $searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(dNSHostName=$currentDomain))"
        $searcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://" + $currentDomain + "/OU=Domain Controllers," + $defaultNamingContext
        $dcObjectPath = $searcher.FindAll() | %{$_.Path}

        # DFSR
        $searchDFSR = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
        $searchDFSR.Filter = "(&(objectClass=msDFSR-Subscription)(name=SYSVOL Subscription))"
        $searchDFSR.SearchRoot = $dcObjectPath
        $dfsrSubObject = $searchDFSR.FindAll()

        if ($dfsrSubObject -ne $null){

            [pscustomobject]@{
                "SYSVOL Replication Mechanism"= "DFSR"
                "Path:"= $dfsrSubObject|%{$_.Properties."msdfsr-rootpath"}
            }

        }

        # FRS
        $searchFRS = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
        $searchFRS.Filter = "(&(objectClass=nTFRSSubscriber)(name=Domain System Volume (SYSVOL share)))"
        $searchFRS.SearchRoot = $dcObjectPath
        $frsSubObject = $searchFRS.FindAll()

        if($frsSubObject -ne $null){

            [pscustomobject]@{
                "SYSVOL Replication Mechanism" = "FRS"
                "Path" = $frsSubObject|%{$_.Properties.frsrootpath}
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check your DFS replication with powershell, you could use the appropriate cmdlets :

```
PS C:\> get-command -Name "*dfsr*"

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName                                                                                       
-----------     ----                                               ----------                                                                                       
Cmdlet          Add-DfsrConnection                                 DFSR                                                                                             
Cmdlet          Add-DfsrMember                                     DFSR                                                                                             
Cmdlet          ConvertFrom-DfsrGuid                               DFSR                                                                                             
Cmdlet          Export-DfsrClone                                   DFSR                                                                                             
Cmdlet          Get-DfsrBacklog                                    DFSR                                                                                             
Cmdlet          Get-DfsrCloneState                                 DFSR                                                                                             
Cmdlet          Get-DfsrConnection                                 DFSR                                                                                             
Cmdlet          Get-DfsrConnectionSchedule                         DFSR                                                                                             
Cmdlet          Get-DfsReplicatedFolder                            DFSR                                                                                             
Cmdlet          Get-DfsReplicationGroup                            DFSR                                                                                             
Cmdlet          Get-DfsrFileHash                                   DFSR                                                                                             
Cmdlet          Get-DfsrGroupSchedule                              DFSR                                                                                             
Cmdlet          Get-DfsrIdRecord                                   DFSR                                                                                             
Cmdlet          Get-DfsrMember                                     DFSR                                                                                             
Cmdlet          Get-DfsrMembership                                 DFSR                                                                                             
Cmdlet          Get-DfsrPreservedFiles                             DFSR                                                                                             
Cmdlet          Get-DfsrServiceConfiguration                       DFSR
```

In particular, `Get-DfsrBacklog` to check if you have files waiting for replication:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-DfsrBacklog -SourceComputerName Server1 -DestinationComputerName Server2).count
4
```

It will give the number of waiting files, and more generally, which file...
You can invert the source and destination to get the replication state of the other side.

**Edit comment**

You can use `dfsrmig.exe /GetGlobalState` to test which replication is used.
If the command return 'dfsr not initalized', **you use FSR**.

Comment: So how do you use these cmdlets to determine if you're using FRS vs DFSR?

Comment: `dfsrmig.exe /GetGlobalState` this returns nothing :(

Comment: It returns nothing? As in no output?

Comment: @joeqwerty yes, it returns nothing, no output. it's just blank

Answer (score 1):

Mind Windows Server 2022 has removed dfsrmig.exe so you can only check whether the FRS or DFS-R Service is running on all Domain Controllers. Additionally starting with Windows Server 2022 it is required to have DFS-R, while previous OS only gave a warning.

You could now use

```
Get-DfsReplicationGroup -IncludeSysvol
```

to check if it does list the "Domain System Volume" replication group.

```
(Get-ADDomainController -Filter *).name | ForEach-Object -Process {Get-Service -ComputerName $_ -Name DFSR,NTFRS} | Sort-Object DisplayName
```

to check the services. FRS should be disabled and DFSR should be running.